# Racket webserver/templates include-template cannot be used with variable

Tags: templates, servlets, racket, procedure, keyword-argument

I am writing a little blog using the Racket webserver (requiring `web-server/templates, web-server/servlet-env, web-server/servlet, web-server/dispatch`). Whenever I want to render a template, I do something this:

```
(define (render-homeworks-overview-page)
  (let
    ([dates
       (sort
         (get-all-homework-dates)
         #:key my-date->string
         string<?)])
    (include-template "templates/homework-overview.html")))
```

Defining a little procedure, to provide the template with all the necessary values, in this case `dates`, which is then used inside the template. This works well so far, but I thought maybe I could get rid of the `let` in all those render procedures, by putting it once into a more abstract `render-template` procedure, which is then called by all the render procedures. Alternatively, the calls to this more abstract procedure could become so simple, that I don't need all the little render procedures anymore. I want to supply the values as keyword arguments and so far I got the following code:

```
(define render-template
  (make-keyword-procedure
    (lambda
      (keywords keyword-args [content "<p>no content!</p>"] [template-path "template/base.html"])
      (let
        ([content content])
        (include-template template-path)))))
```

This would have a default value for the content displayed in the template and a default path for the template to render and take arbitrary keyword arguments, so that any render procedure could supply whatever is needed by a template by giving it as a keyword.

However, I cannot run this code, because there is an error:

```
include-at/relative-to/reader: not a pathname string, `file' form, or `lib' form for file
```

The `template-path` in the call `(include-template template-path)` is underlined red, to indicate that the error is there. However when I replace the `template-path` with an ordinary string like so:

```
(define render-template
  (make-keyword-procedure
    (lambda
      (keywords keyword-args [content "<p>no content!</p>"] [template-path "template/base.html"])
      (let
        ([content content])
        (include-template "templates/base.html")))))
```

The error does not occur. It seems that Racket somehow wants to ensure, that there is a valid path given to `include-template`. But I want that to be a value given to the procedure. Otherwise I cannot write a procedure doing this job.

Also I want the values of the keywords provided to the procedure to be visible to the template. I am not sure, if that is automatically the case, or if I need to put a `let` of some kind around the `include-template` call, because I could not get the code to run yet, to test this.

How can I write such procedure?

As an example of an ideal procedure I'd like to have:

- Jinja2's `render_template`

I can supply any keyword argument I wish and render any template I wish to render. I also do not really understand, why including something like `"rm -rf /"` could damage anything. To me it seems the webserver should simply check *if a file exists* with that name. Obviously it will not exist, so throw an error. How should this ever lead to any unwanted damage? In consequence I do not understand the reasoning behind limiting what can be used as a path to a template to strings (except for workarounds). However, this might be too much for one SO question and should maybe put into another question about the "why" of things.

Comment: The section in the documentation titled [How do I use templates “dynamically"?](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/faq.html#%28part._.How_do_.I_use_templates__dynamically__%29) addresses your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply [`include-template`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/templates.html#%28form._%28%28lib._web-server%2Ftemplates..rkt%29._include-template%29%29) with a *variable* path argument, you can define a render procedure as:

```
(define (dynamic-include-template path)
  (eval #`(include-template #,path)))
```

The procedure takes in any template path as argument and includes that template. For example, `(dynamic-include-template "static.html")` would render `static.html`.

This can be extended to accept any number of keywords and make them available within the template being rendered, as follows:

```
(define render-template
  (make-keyword-procedure
   (lambda (kws kw-args
                [path "templates/base.html"]
                [content "<p>no content!</p>"])
     (for ([i kws]
           [j kw-args])
       (namespace-set-variable-value!
        (string->symbol (keyword->string i)) j))
     (namespace-set-variable-value! 'content content)
     (dynamic-include-template path))))
```

Here, inside the `for` block, keyword values with new identifiers are being set in the top-level environment of namespace using [namespace-set-variable-value!](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Namespaces.html?q=namespace-set-variable-value#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._namespace-set-variable-value%21%29%29), such that for a keyword and value parameter like `(render-template ... #:foo 'bar)`, the corresponding identifier that is made available to the template becomes `foo` (its `@ Syntax` being `@foo`), and its value becomes `bar`.

For example, to render the homework-overview template, you can do:

```
(render-template "templates/homework-overview.html"
                 #:dates (sort (get-all-homework-dates) string<?))
```

then inside `templates/homework-overview.html` you would have:

```
...
@dates
...
```

Take caution, however, when using `eval`, and consider the following for relevant reads:

- [[racket] Dynamic Templates?](https://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2013-October/059885.html)
- [How do I use templates "dynamically"?](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/faq.html#%28part._.How_do_.I_use_templates__dynamically__%29)

Comment: I only have two issues with this solution. One is an error I get, because the function suddenly looks at `path: /home/xiaolong/development/Racket/blog2/htdocs/templates/base.html` and naturally cannot find that file, since there is no `htdocs` folder in my whole project. This is strange, because this answer does not contain `htdocs` at all, so I don't know where it suddenly comes from. The other issue is, that I cannot supply arbitrary keyword arguments to this procedure. When I use `make-keyword-procedure` but still have to use a `let`, how will I know the names of arbitrary keyword-args?

Comment: Maybe I have to set a default path using this aproach?

Comment: For your first issue, I've not been able to reproduce it locally. I created a `templates` directory, under which I stored `static.html` with some content, then tried `(render-template "templates/static.html")` (with `render-template` being defined in the same directory that contains the `templates` folder) and it works as expected, so maybe the problem creating your issue may lie somewhere else in your code.

Comment: For your second issue, one option is to list all possible keywords in your lambda, then create a `[identifier #,keyword]` binding for each possible keyword (similar to how `content` and `dates` keywords have been used above). Keywords that are not used have no effect, so long as they are not present within the template being rendered.

Comment: For the first issue: The thing is, nowhere in my code do I ever mention `htdocs`. It seems like suddenly in the eval expression it thinks "Oh hey it will be in a `htdocs` subfolder.". I even dislike that name, `htdocs` and the templates are no static files either, since they can contain code actually, so I have them in a separate folder named `templates` in the root of the project, next to a folder `static` where all the css, js and images are. And if I do not use the function of this answer, there is no indication of the app ever searching any `htdocs`.

Comment: For the second issue: I actually wanted to avoid having to write every possible keyword, because it could become many with many templates, as the app grows. I thought I could somehow work around having to use a let with arbitrary keywords with `make-keyword-procedure`.

My Ideal would be something like Python `Jinja2`'s `render_template` function, which you may supply any keyword argument you want to and render any template you want.

Comment: @Zelphir I've updated the procedure above so that it can be able to accept any number of keywords without the need to predefine them (such as the `dates` keyword). This should solve your second issue. Let me know if your first issue still persists with this version of the procedure.

Comment: I think I should accept this answer. Something Racket internal seems to have an assumption about a folder named `htdocs` existing (I sure did not add such a name in my app), which it does not in my case. This causes an error and I cannot run the web app when using the procedure you provided in my web app unfortunately. However, the code makes sense and it might work, if I restructured my directory/app structure.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you could try restructuring. Also, `htdocs` seems to be the directory under the default-web-root path. As the [`docs`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/run.html) suggest, "File paths, in addition to the "htdocs" directory under *server-root-path* may be provided with *extra-files-paths*. These paths are checked first, in the order they appear in the list." Also [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server-internal/Web_Servers.html).